# Как указать ширину EditText не в sp, а символах?

Tags: java, android

Разметка

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/etDlg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:maxLength="10"
/>
```

Как указать что ширина не wrap_content, а 10 символов?

Comment: Попробуйте как-то так `android:maxLength="10"`

Comment: Вообще то в примере выше я так и делаю. Это ограничение на количество вводимых символов, а мне надо чтобы изначально ширина была такой же длинны.

Answer (score 0):

Если вам надо установить ширину равную количеству символов, попробуйте заюзать ems

`android:minEms="10"` , только убедитесь, что ширина у `editText` выставлена `wrap_content`

Comment: поле сократилось, но не до 10 символов

Comment: попробуйте выставить размер шрифта в sp

Comment: @kaaa, ширина у символов разная, поэтому вычисляется по самому широкому, чтобы требуемое количество гарантированно уместилось

Comment: А как сделать чтобы вычислялось как мне надо?